# iOS UIWebView Restriction

Tags: ios, webview

I'm trying to do a `UIWebView`, but not allowing the user to visit other part of the given URL. Something like they could only go specific pages where i allow them to go, and not others.

I'm not too sure about the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` method, so I may have made a mistake there. The problem now is that if I enable this method, I am loaded into the `webpage` but am unable to browse. Not even the section i allow.

I would like to know if 1)Am I missing out any important code?, 2)Am I missing anything in the code, or why is my code wrong?

Am new to Xcode, so I will require all the guidance that you guys can give/teach me. Below is my code from the view controller.

EDIT1: Is there any prebuilt method by Xcode, or do I have to create my own method, such that when they are browsing the `UIWebView`, and when they click on another link, if its something other than what I specify, the request get rejected? Is it possible to create a  method such that it will constantly check the absolute url and if it change to something else other than what i specify, it will return to my specified url?

in my.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWebView *webView;  

@end
```

in my .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *currentURL = [[request URL]absoluteString];
    NSRange range1 = [currentURL rangeOfString:@"news"];
    NSRange range2 = [currentURL rangeOfString:@"pdf"];



    if (range1.location ==NSNotFound){
        currentURL = @"http://www.imc.jhmi.edu/news.html";
        [webView reload];
        return YES;
    }else if (range2.location ==NSNotFound){
        currentURL = @"http://www.imc.jhmi.edu/news.html";
        [webView reload];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    webView.delegate = self;

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.imc.jhmi.edu/news.html";
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Comment: It seems your code gets into infinite loop. Remove [webView reload]; from the if condition and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This delegate method **webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType**: is Sent before a web view begins loading a frame. and it Return Value YES if the web view should begin loading content; otherwise, NO.

Your method returns NO when currentURL with range1 and range2 not found.

Comment: Ah! I understand now. thank you very much. Is there any prebuilt method by Xcode or do I have to create my own method such that the method is sent when I click a url in the web view, if it's not what I specify/allow, it redirect to the url I want?